# Can I assign an array to a dynamically created array (using pointers) the way you would normally initialize an array[]?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I tried this following code but it clearly didn't work:

```
    void main3()
{
    int n;
    printf("Input the dimension of the array");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int* testMatrix2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

    testMatrix2 = {512, 51, 642}; //is there a way to do this? "expected an expression" error
}
```

As the comment shows, is there a way to initialize an array as you would normally do without using arrays? I know it's a risky move, but it would make my life easier during testing.

The use of for cycles would not be feasible for me as I need a sort of randomness in the array.

Comment: No, you can't. You can `memcpy(testMatrix2, (int[]){512, 51, 642}, 3* sizeof(int));` though.

Answer (score 1):

As @EugeneSh. stated it is not possible for any size array. If the array has a fixed size you can wrap it into the structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x[10];
}wrappedArray;

void foo(void)
{
    wrappedArray *wa = malloc(sizeof(*wa));

    *wa = (wrappedArray){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are "non-modifiable" L-values. Therefore they cannot be assigned with `=` operator.

However, you could `memcpy` from a compound literal.

```
memcpy(testMatrix2, (const int[]){512, 51, 642}, sizeof(int[3]));
```

Just ensure that `n >= 3` before doing this to avoid Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As the other post already shown how to copy array to dynamically allocated space. Just in case if you don't need to access the array in some other function (or out of scope), then no need to allocate space dynamically. You can use compound literal:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int* testMatrix2 = (int []){512, 51, 642};

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        printf ("%d ", testMatrix2[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out 
512 51 642
```

Compound literals Constructs an unnamed object of specified type in-place.
In this statement of above program

```
int* testMatrix2 = (int []){512, 51, 642};
```

`(int []){512, 51, 642}` is a compound literal. It will create an unnamed automatic array of type `int [3]`, initialise the array to the value `512`, `51` and `642` and the pointer to first element of this array object will be assigned to `testMatrix2`.

Comment: `int* testMatrix2 = (int []){512, 51, 642};` inside a function does not create a static array. It creates an array with automatic storage duration associated with its enclosing block. And the code shown sets the pointer; it does not fill in the dynamically allocated space as the question requests.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Just wanted to show OP that an unnamed array can be created using compound literal and pointer can point to it and access its elements same as it can to a named array. Though, OP is asking to fill in the dynamically allocated space but if there is not need to access the memory reference outside of function/scope then the way I have shown in my post could be a potential way to serve the OP's purpose.